# What is the permissible deviation for a pilot to stop the aircraft when guided by AVDGS?

Tags: airport, taxiing

As per ICAO Annex 14, table 5-4, the permissible deviation for [AVDGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand_guidance_system) is 500mm at stop position, which is the design requirement for AVDGS unit.  I would like to know what is the permissible deviation for the pilot to stop the aircraft when guided by AVDGS, specifically, how far he is permitted to go after the stop signal?